# sort dict by value then if equal by keys

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

i created a  dict, keys=words in list values=count of them. Want to sort them by counts(values) THEN if counts equal sort them by alpha(keys)

```
a = [to, be, or, not, to, be, ae, ae]
w={}
for i in a:
    w[i]=a.count(i)
e=dict(sorted(w.items(),key= lambda a: (a[1],a[0]),reverse=True))
for i, k in e.items():
    print(i , k)
```

what i get now is

```
to 2
be 2
ae 2
or 1
not 1
```

and what i want is

```
ae 2
be 2
to 2
not 1
or 1
```

im noob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reverse=true` applies to both elements of the tuple. That why your alphanumeric output is backwards.

To reverse the order on the first element of the tuple but not on the other you could negate the numbers:

```
sorted(w.items(),key= lambda a: (-a[1],a[0]))
```

---

If you ever run into problem where you need to sort on multiple tuple elements with varying ASC/DESC order and elements that are not easy to negate like integers you could use the following technique.

Modified `multisort` from https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts

Since the sorting is stable the following will work:

```
def multisort(xs, specs):
     for i, reverse in reversed(specs):
         xs.sort(key=lambda x: x[i], reverse=reverse)
     return xs

items = [('to', 2), ('be', 2), ('or', 1), ('not', 1), ('ae', 2)]
multisort(items, [(0, False), (1, True)])
```

Output:

```
[('ae', 2), ('be', 2), ('to', 2), ('not', 1), ('or', 1)]
```

Comment: ohh i didnt know that u can do `lambda a: (-a[1],a[0]))` looks simple should try different cases

Comment: I would like to ask u one more thing its not working in the similar case can u look at it?  `s={'b': 5847, 'c': 560,  'e': 5874}` dict same want to sort them by values if equal then by keys `e = dict(sorted(s.items(), key=lambda a: (-a[1], a[0]))) `  it doesn sort by keys if values equal `{'e': 5874, 'b': 5847, 'c': 560}`

Comment: the values are different in this case, is that not a typo since `5847 != 5874`?

Comment: MY BADDDD SORRY such a noob mistake i just  wrote it wrong

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `reverse` keyword is too blunt for what you want: `sorted` sorts by the tuple, then reverses the result. You only want to reverse sort by the integer. Luckily, you can do that by simply *negating* each integer. (This trick obviously does not work for arbitrary values.)

```
e = dict(sorted(w.items(), key=lambda a: (-a[1], a[0])))
```

In general, you can write your own comparison function:

```
# 1 means x < y
# -1 means x > y
# 0 means x == y
def compare(x, y):
    if x[1] < y[1]:
        return 1
    elif x[1] > y[1]:
        return -1
    elif x[0] < y[0]:
        return -1
    elif x[0] > y[0]:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

then use (`functools.cmp_to_key`)[https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key]:

```
from functools import cmp_to_key

e = dict(sorted(w.items(), key=cmp_to_key(compare)))
```

Comment: thanks! `bad operand type for unary -: 'str'` i tried to change it. does it work only for int? i see now

Comment: Yes; it just takes advantage of the fact that if `x <= y` *numerically*, then `-x >= -y`. Here, your tuples have type `Tuple[str, int]`, so the trick works. It does *not* reverse the direction of the comparison for arbitrary values.

Comment: Update to show an example that lets you write a custom comparison function to use with `sorted`, rather than relying on a function that produces a sort key.

Comment: thaaaanks just started noob examples like that helps a lot  to learn

Comment: *"sorts by the tuple, then reverses the result"* - While true, I find it a bit misleading. Full story is *"reverses the input, then sorts by the tuple, then reverses the result"*. Otherwise it wouldn't be stable.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a custom `sorted` `key` and also a [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instance!

```
from collections import Counter

a = ['to', 'be', 'or', 'not', 'to', 'be', 'ae', 'ae']

for word, count in sorted(
    Counter(a).items(), key=lambda c: (-c[1], c[0])
):
    print(word, count)
```